# Why is there no head function for Seq in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I just discovered `Data.Sequence` and it seems that there is no `head` or `last` function.
I know you can pattern match on `viewL` , or use `index 0`  etc ... But is there a reason such 
basic functiosn are not implemented (or I am missing them ) ?

Answer (score 10):

Using `Prelude.head` is usually considered bad practice: partial functions are always something of a danger; code like

```
if null list then
  ...
 else
  let foo = head list in ...
```

is often written by beginners but would of course better be expressed

```
case list of
  [] -> ...
  (foo:_) ->
```

So in many non-base modules, partial functions are echewed, like in this case. The preferred way is, again, pattern matching – on `viewL`, as you say.

Comment: You could have `head :: Seq a -> Maybe a` ? In many case you wil  have to pattern the `Maybe` but there are lots of functions to deal with it.